# how to build a loop to find the mode of certain values regarding a column within a data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I'm trying to learn how to write loops in R Studio. Hope anyone can help me figure this out...

Given the following data set, how can I write a loop to find out the most popular director (mode) for each movie genre in [this data set](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KG62HGKS7v46cBV62tTM_JYuCWXsmyFy/view?usp=sharing)?

Thanks,

Comment: Tagging the language you're using is essential if you hope to get relevant answers. I've assumed you're using R, if that is incorrect, please edit the tags to replace it with the correct language.

Answer (score 1):

```
f=read.csv("~/Downloads/moviegenres.csv")

table_f=as.matrix(table(f))
for (i in 1:4){ #Since there are four unique movie genres,for each of them 
    #search maximum count(find popular director) then paste name and the max number
    print(paste(names(table_f[i,][table_f[i,]==max(table_f[i,])]),max((table_f[i,])))) 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a loop to count. Here is how to tally by frequency table.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% table
# rearrange to show mode
df %>% table %>% as_tibble() %>% arrange(desc(n))
```

Or in base R, you can use

```
tb=as.data.frame(table(df$Genres, df$Directors))
head(tb[order(tb$Freq, decreasing = T),])
```